# Can I store Google API places location with the placeId?

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

According to developpers.google.com, we can store the placeIDs and refresh them to get the details. I need to get the place nearby **in order by distance over 500 meters**. I don't know how to do it without the location storing.
Can I store the place locations with the placeIds according to developpers.google.com?
Thank you for you replies.
SyLaDe

Comment: I've closed this as part of closing a number of [tag:google-places-api] questions which are asking for legal interpretations of what it is that's *permitted* to be stored. Such questions are not about programming. They are legal questions. For this question, given the wording, it sounds like you're asking what is *permitted*, rather than what is *functional*. However, I can also see an interpretation where you might have been asking about function. If you are asking about function, rather than permission, then please [edit] this question to be clearer that's the case, so it can be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, Google Maps place_id is just the key to request basic information about that place (and it's free) or you can request detail information such as contact and atmosphere (with additional charge).

If you wanna get the place nearby in order by the distance over 500 meters, you can simply use Nearby Search requests under Place API.

for example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-6.321516009,106.86227379999998&radius=500&key=yourkey
```

and you will get json result that you can store and organize.

To get longitude and latitude, you can manually choose from google maps, or you can get it from GIS tool with coordinates acquisition.

Comment: The queries Nearby Search give only the first twenty places. To have the places over 500m, I must run several queries. Other problem: if I want to search the bar, cafe, restaurant places, I must to run several queries for each type (bar, ...). That's a lot of queries and it isn't free! I would store the types and the locations (latitude/longitude or GIS geography) and run one time a stored procedure to get the all places nearby in order by the distance over 500m. From this result, i can use the request basic information about each place. I don't know it is possible with the Developer Policies.

Comment: I see, but I'm sorry how do you store all nearby placeIDs without doing Place Search?

Comment: In my PostgreSQL server with a table containing two (or three) columns "placeID", "location" (and "type"). I can use the GIS function ST_Distance() to calculate the places distance. Am I allowed to do that?